# How to create a loop in javascript (for use in Chrome -> Console)

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

I am viewing a webpage with a lazy load structure (similar to facebook's wall), such that when a user loads the page and scrolls down, more content is loaded if available.

I want to view this page in Chrome, and inject a script via the console to infinitely scroll down the page so I can get the last available entry.

This code works for 1 instance:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

How can I make it scroll infinitely with 1.5 secs between scrolls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat some lines of code over a set interval, then you should look at [window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval). For your case you could do

```
var scrollInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
}, 1500);
```

Although that's probably not the best way to go about it because god help you if you do it on a page that has thousands of posts available like facebook. If ever you want to stop it you can enter into the console:

```
window.clearInterval(scrollInterval);
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I set this to loop to a specific number then?

Comment: You mean only scroll a certain number of times? In that case I would use a for loop and wrap your code in a window.setTimeout of 1500ms each time